# Define member variables of class inside function

Tags: c++, class, initialization

I know there have been multiple posts regarding this topic, but I feel like my situation is a bit different. I don't know if what I am trying to do is possible, and if it is not, please let me know! Right now, I have code that looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Something
{
   public:
    string location;
    string isLocal;
    string IPAddress;
    string setString(string key)
    {
          //key will be either location, isLocal, or IPAddress  
          //set that value to "found" so when I call the member variable later, it will output found
    }

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  DLNA local;
  string answer = local.setString("IPAddress");
  cout << local.IPAddress; // should return "found"
  return 0;
}
```

Basically, inside the function setString, I am trying to initialize the member variable to a default value based on what string is passed in. However, I don't seem to know how to do this. Just declaring a local DLNA and setting its value inside the setString function doesn't seem to have any impact when I call the member variables inside the main function. Does anyone know how I can solve my problem, or if this is even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Initialize **which** member variable?

Comment: In this case, setting IPAddress. There is no way I could set a member variable without hard coding it in right? For example, if key, the parameter, was isLocal, is there a way I could have the program set isLocal to "found"?

Comment: Er, why don't you just use an if block?

Comment: ...Can't believe I didn't think of that. I do have 20 member variables in my actual file, so it would be a bit of a nuisance, but for now, it's all I got. Thanks!

Comment: You should probably revisit your design then.  I don't know exactly what  you're doing, but setting one of 20 variables and ignoring the rest based on a string feels off.

Comment: There is no way I could loop through the member variables, is there? Was thinking I could just store them all in one array, but I've read that its not possible in C++. Is that true? @Donnie

Comment: Loop through the variables?  No.  You could make a map of strings to values if you really needed to do something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want this right?
Look closely at that endl right after the cout. That will flush "things out". So it will print on the screen the output. Try running it without that endl. Hope this helps

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Something
{
   public:
    string location;
    string isLocal;
    string IPAddress;
    string setString(string key)
    {
        if (key == "location") 
        {
            location = "found";
            return location;
        }
        else if (key == "isLocal") 
        {
            isLocal = "found";
            return isLocal;
        }
        else if (key == "IPAddress") 
        {
            IPAddress = "found";
            return IPAddress;
        }

        return "not found";
    }

};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Something local;
  string answer = local.setString("IPAddress");
  cout << local.IPAddress << endl; // should return "found"
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/11252/) for a discussion about exactly the problem of getting the name of a variable as a string. In short - **no you can't do it**, although there are ways to emulate it they make your code hard to understand and you should do things differently.

In your situation you could have something like this for the `setString` member function

```
string setString(string key)
{
    if (key == "location") {
        location = "found";
    } elseif (key == "isLocal") {
    if (key == "isLocal") {
        isLocal = "found";
    } elseif (key == "IPAddress") {
        IPAddress = "found";
    } else {
        // handle unmatched case somehow (error message)
    }
    return "found";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The other user answered a bit earlier so I awarded him the answer, but your code also works!